# How do I handle moving data from tinyint into a text field

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a field which stores data (e.g. 1, 0) in a `tinyint`(1) column, and I have to move this into a `text` column and a simple transformation stores the data in text field with additional spaces instead of just 1 or 0. How should I do this correctly?

```
create table A (id, foo tinyint(1));
create table B (id, bar text);
```

I am trying to copy all elements of A into B using `insert into B (id, bar) select id, foo from A;` which is causing the transformation problem.

Comment: Define "additional spaces". Show the query that works unexpectedly.

Comment: No it is getting stored with additional spaces, but I don't want any space to be concatenated at the end. Since if I search with '1' or '1 ' or '1 ' it seems to match, which is incorrect, the comparison should match only for '1' or '0' and not something with '1 and number of spaces here'

Comment: Show us the matching query you use, please.

Comment: @Gustav - I have modified the question, which contains the insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your insert statement. The problem lies with the way MySQL compares strings.

Even the following query will match:

```
SELECT * FROM B where TRIM(bar) = '1   ';
```

The following works correctly (IE, does not match):

```
SELECT * FROM B where bar LIKE '1 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL masters implicit conversion. Since you are converting a number to a string type, I don't see any problem which could occur. Therefore, something like `UPDATE table1 SET text_column = CONCAT(' ',tinyint_column,' ')` should work.

Comment: Quote from OP : `with additional spaces instead of just 1 or 0`

Comment: @Dems Sorry, i must have missed that. Edited the answer

Comment: No it is getting stored with additional spaces, but I don't want any space to be concatenated. Since if I search with '1' or '1 ' or '1  ' it seems to match, which is incorrect.